# Kodaira embedding theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(M,L)$ be a compact Kahler manifold with polarization $L$, i.e. $c_1(L)>0$. Then Kodaira embedding theory says that any basis of $H^0(M,L^\mathcal k)$ for $k$ sufficiently large, gives an embedding of $M$ into some projective space $\mathbb CP^N$ where, $N+1=\text {dim}H^0(M,L^\mathcal k)$.

Question:

> Let $(M,L)$ be a compact Kahler manifold with  $c_1(L)=0$, or negative
>   first Chern class. Then can we have an embedding of $M$ to $\mathbb
> CP^N$ ? is there any counterexample?

Comment: Are you asking whether a map to projective space induced by a power of $L$ can be an embedding if $L$ is not positive? This is not possible. Or is the question *is there an $M$ which can be embedded into projective space, even though there exists a line bundle $L$ with trivial (resp. negative) first Chern class?*

Comment: Do you still need answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence seems to be incomplete: did you mean to write "$c_1(L)$ is positive"?

As for the main question: there are lots of compact Kähler manifolds that cannot be embedded in projective space – for example, a very general K3 surface.

On the other hand, just choosing an *arbitrary* line bundle $L$ on $M$ with $c_1(L)=0$ (or negative) cannot give you any information about $M$ itself: why not take $L=\mathcal O_M$, for instance?

Comment: Yes, $c_1(L)>0$ positive in first statement.

Comment: @1234: The comment of Ben A. above makes me re-think whether I have answered what you are really asking. Can you edit the question to clarify what relationship you seek between $L$ and the embedding?

Comment: I mean hear $(M,L)$ is a polarized variety so by kodaira embedding, it ca be embedded in $\mathbb CP^n$

Comment: @1234: your last comment is even less clear. Say _clearly_ what you are asking about this embedding, and how it is related with $L$; otherwise, nobody can answer your question